# Why does the screenshot does not copy until the edge of my screen?

Tags: c#, screenshot, scale, scaling

Why the screenshot does not copy until the edge of my screen?

Is there code that can detect windows scaling?  My laptop is scaled at 150%.  My actual resolution is at 1920 x 1080, but C# detects only 1820 x 720

[image]

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
g.CopyFromScreen(
   Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y, 0,
   0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
```

Comment: It is not entirely clear from your screenshot what is actually shown. What portion of the screen was copied?

Comment: I found the problem: windows scaling--my resolution is 1920 x 1080 but my scale is at 150% so the pixel only read 1280 x 720.

Comment: solved: here's the code

Comment: @user122289 How you solved that? where is the code?